# Error: BC30201 IN ssrs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I'm getting

> The value expression for the text run
>   'PAYEE_NAME.Paragraphs[0].Textruns[0]' contains an error BC30201" for:

```
=iif(isnothing(First(Fields!PAYEE_NAME.Value, "AddressDetails")),"",(First(Fields!PAYEE_NAME.Value, "AddressDetails")+vbcrlf))+
iif(isnothing(First(Fields!ADDRESSLINE1.Value, "AddressDetails")),"",(First(Fields!ADDRESSLINE1.Value, "AddressDetails")))
```

But not for:

```
=replace(iif(isnothing(First(Fields!PAYEE_NAME.Value, "AddressDetails")),"",(First(Fields!PAYEE_NAME.Value, "AddressDetails")+vbcrlf))+
iif(isnothing(First(Fields!ADDRESSLINE1.Value, "AddressDetails")),"",(First(Fields!ADDRESSLINE1.Value, "AddressDetails")))
," ","")
```

why? How do I solve this? The second expression removes spaces between words and I don't need that. I want it as, if there is payee name for a payee then display it, If not go to 2nd line and do the same.

Comment: That error generally means there is something wrong with the Boolean expression.  Try stepping into your expression in pieces.  For example, start with iif(isnothing(First(Fields!PAYEE_NAME.Value, "AddressDetails")),"True","False") and see what the result is.  If that works, continue adding your expression in pieces until you hit the error again.

Comment: Yes,I tried that. It worked for one iif condtion. But with multiple iif additions it showed the error. Seems like, have to add '(' and ')' at the beginning and end of the combined set of iif conditions.

Comment: Can you try putting the Payee_Name and AddressLine1 value into separate placeholders in the same textbox.  That should remove the need for the iif statements.  Also can Payee_Name be ""?  If yes, that would result in "" + vbcrlf which may not be what you want either.